# I am trying a facebook link but it's not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I am trying to make a link for facebook but I am totally lost :)
Can you help? I got the code from the internet!

Code:

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
  natilink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nati);

  natilink .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    try {
         String uri = "fb://page/" + natgeo;    
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
         startActivity(intent);   
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
     String uri = "http://touch.facebook.com/pages/x/" + natgeo;   
     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriMobile));    
     startActivity(i); 
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope I could help you. The Facebook package on your phone is called "com.facebook.kantana". Copy & paste the following.

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
   i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
if (i == null)
    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Update:

Just put this in your onClick method:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setClassName("com.facebook.kantana,
                        "com.xxx.your_class_name");//Add your class Name here

                startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This only works with the browser, I want to run in the application, if it's not there; it goes to facebook play google

Comment: Therefore you Need the Facebook app package Name which is com.facebook.katana. I will edit my answer with the new code.

Comment: Ok check out the answer. You simply have to start a new activity when the button is clicked. :D